# Stuck on immersivelabs sudo

Tags: linux, sudo

I have a lab to complete that requires the following:

Become the ‘pseudo’ user, using the previously discovered password. What is the token contained in the file `/root/token.txt`?

I have completed the first part and become user pseudo.
The second part I am stuck on, whenever I try to access the root folder I get:

> pseudo@sudo:/$ cd /root//token.txt
>   bash: cd: /root//token.txt: Permission denied
>   pseudo@sudo:/$

I know I am doing something obviously wrong and have got to the stage of not being able to see the wood for the trees, but any advice would be gratefully received.

Comment: Pseudo-user, not being root, obviously can't access the /root folder. Maybe you should try it with `sudo`? Since this is a lab/homework question, you should ask for your teacher/tutor for help.

Comment: unfortunately its an online lab only so no tutor. I'll keep trying

Answer (score 0):

Try this way (if you finished first part)

- Switch on Pseudo user account (command: su pseudo) - Password obtained in first part of this lab is needed
- Use any text editor to find token value (command: sudo vi /root/token.txt)

Answer (score 0):

Try using this command, after you assume pseudo user:

```
sudo cat root/token.txt
```